# How to change suffix: bundle into webplugin in the folder Products with Xcode Project?

Tags: cocoa, xcode

I wang to develop a plugin with safari, now I new a Project with bundle . then I know that if the plugin work , the app.webplugin will be put into the folder:/Library/internet plugins.
But when I rename the suffix of app.bundle in the Products folder of project tree into app.webplugin , then when I rebuild , I find that in debug folder the app.bundle will appear again. I saw some example that when they build, some app.plunin or app.webplugin will apear in the debug folder, why? If can I rename the app.bundle to app.webplugin in the Products folder directly? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click on your target in the Xcode group listing and select Get Info.

In the Build tab, change the "Wrapper Extension" setting to the string you want to use for the file extension of your bundle.